# Getting an image to link to a web page in a GridView on Android?

Tags: android, image, gridview, hyperlink

I have an app with the GridView layout have a single image for testing purposes until I figure out this next step. I have everything set up, but I don't know how implement a design where image A, B, C, D, etc. are clicked result in the user (me) landing on a webpage that I specify. I need each image to link to different locations and I would really appreciate the help to implement this into my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create new ImageView for each item
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } 

        else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.A, R.drawable.B,
        R.drawable.C, R.drawable.D,
        R.drawable.E, R.drawable.F,
        R.drawable.G, R.drawable.H,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getItemId() in your adapter (just return the position) to select the URL you want to go to. Just like you have mThumbIds, just have a parallel array that holds the matching URLs, so when an image is clicked, its corresponding URL can be accessed easily at the same index.

Comment: Could you give an example with like google.com ? This is my first time using the grid view and I just learned it today and its still bouncing around in my head.

Answer (score 0):

The "zero-work" method of doing this would be to simply launch an Intent that would open the URL in the device's browser from an OnItemClickListener.  Something like:

```
//Obtain a reference to the view in your layout somehow...I chose findViewById()
GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.peters_grid);
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //"position" is the location of the image clicked
        String url = arrayOfUrls[position];
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Where you are grabbing the correct URL for each position from an array of Strings.  This is just one idea for getting the right URL...you could construct the proper URL a million different ways, but the key is to pass it to the `Intent` and then fire it.

The "little work" version of this would be to create a `WebView` in this or another `Activity` so you can load the web page and stay within your application code.  If the `WebView` is in a second `Activity`, it would still be best to use an Intent to pass the URL string from the first `Activity` to the second.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks, do you have a good link on how to make the WebView, I would prefer to keep it all in the app, instead of having to launch the Browser like I currently do..

Comment: Try the Using WebViews article in the SDK documentation, it has a link to a sample project as well: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html